# table with blank caption but table label

Tags: tables, captions

If I don't put a caption on my table, I don't get the "Table 2.2" label underneath it.  If I add a blank caption, I get "Table 2.2:".  How do I get rid of the ":"?

I am using `memoir` and `threeparttable`.  Within the `threeparttable`, I am using a `tabular`, but I don't think that matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to load extra packages; `memoir` is a very versatile class that offers its own features, in this case, `\captiondelim`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\begin{table}
\centering
\rule{2cm}{2cm}
\captiondelim{}
\caption{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Remark: in fact, loading `caption` with the `memoir` class triggers a warning:

> Class memoir Warning: You are using the caption package with the
>   memoir class. This may cause unexpected or inconsistent results if you
>   use any of memoir's captioning facilities.

Answer (score 1):

add `\usepackage{caption}` in the preamble. It should automatically remove the colon before empty captions.

Comment: Thank you, this works.  It's surprising that `memoir` doesn't automatically include `caption`.  Does `caption` interfere with `ccaption`, which is automatically included by `memoir`?

Comment: I didn't use the ccaption or memoir packages before and my undestanding of LaTeX in general is still limited... If i had to guess, i'd say it depends on which you include first.